# Использование переменной, которой может быть не присвоено значение в блоке finally

Tags: c#, visual-studio, null, try-catch

Это весь код функции. Может кто-нибудь мне объяснить, при каких, гипотетически, условиях переменной `response` может быть не присвоено значение?

Или же это просто причуды vs?

```
string method = ExtractMethod(context.Request.RawUrl ?? string.Empty);
IHandlerFactory handlerFactory = GetHandlerFactory(method);
IHandler handler;
Response response;
try
{
    handler = handlerFactory.Create(context);
    response = handler.ProcessRequest();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.Log(LogSeverity.Error, nameof(HttpHandler), "Error", e);
    response = new()
    {
        Exception = CoreException.UnknownException
    };
}
finally
{
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(context.Response.OutputStream, response);
    context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
}
```

[image: Скриншот из студии]

Comment: например, если у вас вылетает эксепшон тут `handler = handlerFactory.Create(context);`, а потом тут `Logger.Log(LogSeverity.Error, nameof(HttpHandler), "Error", e);`, то в блоке `finally` непонятно какое значение будет у `response`. Чтобы всем было всё понятно, положите туда сразу что нибудь, хотя бы просто null `Response response = null;`

Comment: а разве если в блоке catch вылетит исключение, оно не остановит выполнение всей программы?

Comment: finally уберите вообще, смысл здесь в нем какой, если catch ловит всё что можно?

Comment: резонно вообще. ну вопрос я решил инициализацией response изначально, как и посоветовал tym32167. просто интересная ситуация, с которой я раннее ни разу не сталкивался, поэтому и стало интересно. видимо try-catch немного не так обрабатывается анализатором, как то же if-else, например, вот и чудит.

Comment: Если `response` не присвоено значение, то нет смысла сериализовать его. Добавить в `finally` проверку `if (response != null)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас в блоке `try` и `catch` вылетают исключения, то `finally` все равно выполнится. Чтобы было понятно что делать с response в этом случае, положите туда сразу что нибудь, хотя бы просто `Response response = null;`

Пример

```
    try
    {           
        throw new Exception("oops");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("oops again");      
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Im finally block!");
    }
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кстати, у меня почему-то все равно падает ислючение, и просто все останавливается. и finally в том числе. и в дебаге и в релизе... просто печатает сообщение об ошибке и виснет.

Comment: ну так второе исключение же не ловится. Заверните всю конструкцию в еще один большой try-catch https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YxGg.png

Comment: хм... ну это уже другой совершенно разговор. впрочем, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: в моем примере из ответа первое исключение ловится конструкцией catch. А второе не ловится ничем, отчего у вас программа падает. А finally вызывается в любом случае, не важно где ловится или не ловится исключение, не важно было ли исключение вообще, finally вызовится все равно.